# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi on half of the time

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

Most of the time when I power on my computer into Ubuntu 22.04, I have no wifi at all. As in, there is no wifi icon. I suspect it means that it fails to find the wifi hardware. When I restart the machine, the wifi icon is there and the system works as expected. This machine also has Windows 10 installed as dual boot. On windows, the wifi works no problem. How can I debug this problem?

The wifi card is a built-in card of my motherboard, MSI MPG Z690 Force Wifi. In the data sheet the build-in wifi card is called simply `Intel® Wi-Fi 6E module`, however, I could try to find its exact model if it is relevant.

Response of `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 11
       serial: 10:a5:1d:8f:d0:5e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf-a0-72.uc ip=192.168.79.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:18 memory:620311c000-620311ffff
```

**Edit 1**: As requested, here is the response of `inxi -N`

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V driver: igc
```

Comment: `inxi -N` would help.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555, thanks a lot. I can't tell for sure yet, but I could not reproduce the bug right now after removing fast boot. If you wish to post this as an answer I will accept. Also, are the two answers below ChatGPT bots? :D I have never seen something like this before

Comment: I strongly suspect they are AI bots. The "answers" are far from helpful which is why they are downvoted and nominated for deletion. My suggestion is, in my opinion, too trivial to be an answer but thanks for the offer.